# How to sync windows explorer with windows command prompt?

Tags: c++, winapi

Is there a way to control/navigate windows explorer from the windows command prompt? Or just sync explorer with the prompt's current directory?

If for example I enter the command "c:>cd d:\folder\" in the prompt, the prompt's current directory will change right? What I'm aiming for is that as soon as prompt's directory changes the explorer will do too same with the prompt's current directory.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Can you give an example?

Answer (score 1):

You can issue the command  `explorer .` to open an explorer window in the current directory